# How to create registration page for users on own website?

Tags: django, django-models

I am currently working on a GST portal for software project. I am learning and implementing Django for backend. Currently, I know that the users in django are for the admin page. How to I create my own separate users for my website. To be specific, I have 2 types of users- Taxpayer and tax-official who can register on my website. How do I do that?

Desperate help needed.

Comment: You r best bet is to work through the tutorial included in Django - it is very clear and will help you better understand how things work in the framework. This is a good tutorial, too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication

Answer (score 0):

You can create a userprofile model like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

TAX_PAYER = 'tax_payer'
TAX_OFFICIAL = 'tax_official'
USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('tax_payer', 'Tax Payer'),
    ('tax_official', 'Tax Official')
)


class UserProfile(User):
    role = models.TextField(max_length=20, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Comment: That's my issue, I don't want the users to be accessed from admin page, rather from my own website

Comment: Then don't register the UserProfile model. And it will no longer be accessible from admin